# how to use linqkit within for loop in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

my code is work when array length==1.
when my array length is greater than 1 than i am getting wrong list data.

```
    var classtime = PredicateBuilder.True<ServiceManual>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Category.Length; i++)
            {
                long? cateID = Convert.ToInt64(Category[i]);
                if (Category.Length == 1)
                {
                    classtime = classtime.And(i => i.CategoryID == cateID);
                }
                else
                {
                    classtime = classtime.Or(i => i.CategoryID == cateID);
                }
            }
var lstclasssCate = context.tblServiceManual.Where(classtime.Compile()).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you aware that you are adding the same And clause when Category.Length==1 and Category.Length !=1

Comment: yeah but i am use classtime.Or but i also get wrong list data. i update the code

Comment: And just a hint, it is more difficult to read your code when you are reusing the same variable names, consider changing `classtime.And(i => i.CategoryID == cateID):` to use another variable name than your iterating variable e.g. `classtime.And(ct => ct.CategoryID == cateID);`

Comment: What does wrong list data mean? And have you tried debugging the code to ensure the result of classTime.compile contains the expected conditions?

Comment: mean i am getting all list data instead of these IDs data.

Comment: Then i guess you need to split it up into two blocks, one handling the or case (starting with `var orPart = PredicateBuilder.False<ServiceManual>();` and the other case starting with `var andPart = PredicateBuilder.True<ServiceManual>();`

Comment: What is your version of asp.net core project and LiqKit?And what is your error message?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong, code won't compile (referencing i inside loop that is already using i), and you are doing it the hard way.

Just call this:

```
var cats = Category.Select(c=>Convert.ToInt64(c)).ToArray();
var lstclasssCate = context.tblServiceManual
  .Where(t=>cats.Contains(t.CategoryID))
  .ToList();
```

The hard way:

```
var classtime = PredicateBuilder.False<ServiceManual>();
foreach(var catId in Category.Select(c=>Convert.ToInt64(c)))
{
  classtime = classtime.Or(i => i.CategoryID == catId);
}
var lstclasssCate=context.tblServiceManual
  .Where(classtime.Compile())
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used asp.net core 2.2 and LinqKit 1.1.7.It could display all the list data.

1.Model:

```
public class ServiceManual
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

2.Controller(you could not use `i` in linq):

```
public class ServiceManualsController : Controller
{
    private readonly MVC2Context _context;

    public ServiceManualsController(MVC2Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

        // GET: ServiceManuals
    public List<ServiceManual> Index()
    {
        var Category = new int[] { 1,2,3};
        var classtime = PredicateBuilder.True<ServiceManual>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Category.Length; i++)
        {
            long? cateID = Convert.ToInt64(Category[i]);
            if (Category.Length == 1)
            {
                classtime = classtime.And(c => c.Id == cateID);
            }
            else
            {
                classtime = classtime.Or(c => c.Id == cateID);
            }
        }
        var lstclasssCate = _context.tblServiceManual.Where(classtime.Compile()).ToList();
        return lstclasssCate;
    }
```

3.Result:
[image]